# SQL USE database_name not not found

Tags: sql-server

I am *super new* to SQL (as in, this is my first time ever seeing it) and I'm having some trouble getting it working. I am using SQL Server 2014. So far, this is literally all I have written:

```
CREATE DATABASE foo;

USE foo;
```

The second foo is underlined, and it says "Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'foo'. No entry found with that name" What am I doing wrong/not understanding here? I can't find any other answers online.

Comment: You need to update your intellisense cache. ctrl+shift+r. But @Dave is correct. They must be in separate batches.

Comment: Ah I see, so now the red line is gone, but now it gives an error (runtime, it appears) saying that Database 'foo' does not exist.

Comment: Nevermind I see I had to add GO. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

separate the commands with a 'GO'

```
create database foo;
GO
use foo
```